# How do I use SWIG in Perl?

Tags: perl, swig

I am totally new to `SWIG` interfaces and how to use this with C and Perl.

It will a great help to me, if someone explains about using `Perl` and `C` with `SWIG`.

Comment: You say in one comment that you're not sure which is the best way. If you tell us what you are trying to do (rather than how you are trying to solve it), we might be able to recommend the best way.

Comment: see http://www.swig.org/papers/Perl98/swigperl.htm - Perl Extension Building with SWIG.

Comment: Check out http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils::XSpp for an alternative to SWIG. Caveat: I'm a co-author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be these will help you:

- [Using SWIG to interface scripting languages with C/C++](http://linuxgazette.net/issue49/pramode.html)
- [Using SWIG, a simple example for perl](http://drupal.star.bnl.gov/STAR/blog-entry/jeromel/2009/apr/30/using-swig-simple-example-perl-and-java)

Comment: can you give me a link for Perl and C using SWIG ?? pls

Comment: @Senthil: Above links have examples.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take a look at [`Inline::C`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline)? It has all the power of SWIG but it is so much easier to get up and running with it.

Comment: well, actually i dont know which is the best way. Let me look at every possibility. If Inline::C works fine, then i will stick to it

Comment: Waaait. Inline::C is the devil when it comes to deployment. It's not impossible, but it's damn inconvenient. If what you're writing is to run on a machine other than a development machine, I suggest you stay away from it.

Comment: The downside to `Inline::C` is that the machine that runs the code must have a C compiler.  I have also had problems with corrupt `Inline::C` caches (this has occurred when several programs try to use a module that uses `Inline::C` at the same time and the cache didn't exist yet).  I find `Inline::C` is great for prototyping, but XS is much better for production.